# newbie question - Numpy reshape change not longer fits on model

Tags: python, numpy, keras

The following is a story of the code that runs ok, but doesn't perform the expected job.

I'm using LTSM for series prediction and seemed to work well.
I reshaped my 6000 numbers of data in the format 1 feature with 6 timesteps and 1000 of samples.

```
fileCSV = open("Input.csv") 
input_seq= np.loadtxt(fileCSV, delimiter=",")
X = input_seq.reshape(1000,6,1)
```

And the same for the output data.
The LTSM model was working ok:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(600, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,1))))

...more model code ….

history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=1000)
```

What happened was, after looking to the results when increase the size of the network and the epochs, all the six predictions were converging to the same number, which doesn't make sense because they are independent variables.
I realize that maybe I was wrong: it should be 6 features with one timestep and 1000 samples.
But after changing the reshape and model to...

```
# changes:
X = input_seq.reshape(1000,1,6) <<< changed!
....
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(600, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,6))))<<< changed!

...more model code...

history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1, batch_size=1000)
```

Then I got one error because in the fit model was expecting and shape (6,1) and got (1,6).

I don’t understand why in the model.fit expects different from what was defined in the model...
Maybe I'm tired in a Sunday afternoon and cannot see the obvious...

Any light on this will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nobody answer my question, I started to consider that  maybe my code was correct and the problem was in other place. As a matther of fact, the solution was to change from 6-1 to 1-6 in this parte of the code:

```
# repeat vector
model.add(RepeatVector(1)) 
# decoder layer
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(6)))
```

If you had the same newbie problem, drop a comment so I can see I´not the only one! :)